# Check duplicate user name with client-side validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a one input type and button, which are used to enter username into the SQL database via ajax.

Now I want to achieve the **validation** that checks the duplicate names. If duplicate exists an error message will be shown, any help regarding this

```
<div id="Div1">
    <label>FormName</label>
    <input type="text" id="Text1" placeholder="Type form name here" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div id="Div2" style="float: right;">
    <input type="button" id="Button2" class="btn btn-default" style="" value="Save Form" />
    <input type="button" id="Button3" class="btn btn-success" style="" value="Add Section" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how it will roughly look:

**Back end**

- prepare SQL query that will check for duplicates
- expose it on your server, perhaps as RESTful API or WCF

**Front end**

- add an ajax call to your back end service
- hook this call to an event, perhaps when user shift focus to another text box or maybe press a `check` button

Comment: can you provide any example for this validation

Comment: @Jot It should be pretty straightforward. If you're stuck on a specific part, then ask about that specific part.

Comment: @jot something similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982420/asp-net-custom-validator-webmethod-jquery ..

Comment: @Jot there is quite a bit of code and it depends on your approach. Try implementing it and ask a specific question otherwise it's just too much for a short and helpful answer