# Writing WebMethod and Calling it Through AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem, my problem is that I have a Bootstrap Modal that needs to display on the click of a linkbutton, alos when the link button is pressed, it will fire a method that fills a table in the modal body with a result set from a query.

I think the only solution to this is to make the method a `WebMethod` and call it through AJAX in ASP.NET page.

I will post my code below :

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:LinkButton href="#viewemydevices" data-toggle="modal" ID="ViewMyDevices" runat="server" OnClick="btnViewMyDevices_Click">
<div class="panel-footer announcement-bottom">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
          View Devices
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
              <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
</asp:LinkButton>

<div class="modal fade" id="viewemydevices" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>This is a section</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table id="MyDevicesTable" class="table tbody" runat="server" visible="false">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DataGrid ID="MyDevicesGrid" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped tbody" Visible="false"
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                                    ForeColor="black"
                                    HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                                    HeaderStyle-ForeColor="black"
                                    GridLines="None"
                                    EnableViewState="false"
                                    AllowSorting="True"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**C#**

```
protected void btnViewMyDevices_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectMyDevices = "My Query, it works fine";

        sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(selectMyDevices, sqlConn);
        sqlConn.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdrMyDevices = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        //reads row into datagrid
        if (rdrMyDevices.HasRows)
        {
            //sets table/grid to visible
            MyDevicesGrid.Visible = true;
            MyDevicesTable.Visible = true;

            //adds data to grid
            MyDevicesGrid.DataSource = rdrMyDevices;
            MyDevicesGrid.DataBind();
        }
        sqlConn.Close();
    }
```

What I am looking for is for someone to help me mark up a WebMethod for my below method and how exactly to call that in my ASP.NET.... I know it needs to be a static method...

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look here - it's about some issue with validation, however you have everything there: how to write web method, how to call it from jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982420/asp-net-custom-validator-webmethod-jquery